# Navigate Downwards to next closest Flexbox Item between Rows?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flexbox

I have a list of Boxes that I show next to one another in a wrapped flex container. Users can navigate them and go to the previous/next box by pressing buttons. The currently selected box is displayed in a different color:

```
import React, { useState } from "react"
import styled from "styled-components"

const Box = styled.div`
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: ${props => (props.selected ? `red` : `blue`)};
  margin: 10px;
`

const Wrapper = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  max-width: 500px;
`
const Test = () => {
  const boxes = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState(0)

  return (
    <>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          setSelected(selected + 1)
        }}
      >
        Next item
      </button>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          // ??
        }}
      >
        Go Down
      </button>
      <Wrapper>
        {boxes.map(box => {
          return <Box selected={selected === box}>{box}</Box>
        })}
      </Wrapper>
    </>
  )
}

export default Test
```

When my flex-container wraps those boxes and there are multiple rows, I would like to also allow the user to click a button to go down a row, to the next item underneath the currently selected box.

The Problem is that unlike in the example here, boxes will be of different sizes and the flexbox container `max-width` will also not be known. So I can't do a simple calculations like `3 boxes per row = the currently selected box number + 3` etc.

Is there any way or any idea that would solve this elegantly?

*PS: I tried to convert this into a JSFiddle, but didn't know how to include `styled-components` as an external library. Any help would be appreciated. [Here is my JSFiddle Attempt](https://jsfiddle.net/oeq1uw08/), I don't know yet why it's not working, but working on it!